# Print output live and save it to a variable at the same time

Tags: bash, platform-agnostic

I know that I can [save the output to a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4651437/how-to-set-a-variable-to-the-output-of-a-command-in-bash) and *then* print it:

```
VAR=$(command)
echo "$VAR"
```

But this has a number of drawbacks:

- I won't see the progress of the command as it goes.

  - In particular, will see all `stdout` output after all `stderr` output, making it hard to match them.
- Since this will result in no output for the duration of the command's work, in some environments (like Travis CI) this will terminate the job if the command works for long enough.

**So, how can I save the output and also see it live on the console?**

- Portable solutions are preferrable though a Linux/MacOS-only one will do in a pinch.
- A solution should not have undesirable side effects in `errexit` mode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the top of my head, one can `tee` the output to an additional file descriptor set to the original stdout:

```
exec 3>&1
VAR=$(command | tee /dev/fd/3)
```

One needs to have `set -o pipefail` set to detect `command`'s error in `errexit` mode.

Answer (score 0):

This will also work

```
VAR=$(command | tee /dev/tty)
```

Comment: Stdout is not necessarily `/dev/tty`.

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev if I don't have `/dev/tty` there will be no printout to the screen but only set the result to VAR.

Comment: I mean, the output of an encompassing compound command or the entire script can be redirected so that it's not `/dev/tty`. In this case, printing directly to `/dev/tty` with have an undesired effect.

Comment: works on my localhost, but on bitbucket pipeline, it shows error `tee: /dev/tty: No such device or address`